# Compare standard devation between different samples?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, sample

I am calculating standard deviations $\hat\sigma_i$ from many samples from distributions with mean equal to zero but different variances $N(0, \sigma_i^2)$. Each sample has different size $N$. When comparing $\hat\sigma_i$, should I divide each standard deviation by square root of sample size $\sqrt{N}$ or not?

Answer (score 1):

In your problem you are comparing the variances of distributions where the mean is known. The division by $\sqrt{N}$ is used when you are comparing the means of distributions by using the sample mean. This is because for a sample $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$,

$$\bar{X}_n \sim N\left(\mu, \dfrac{\sigma^2}{N} \right). $$

However, in your problem you are *not* comparing the means of the distributions, but comparing the variances. So you need to look at the sampling distribution of the sample variance.

Say you have $k$ different distributions from which you have samples of varying sizes.
\begin{align*}
& X_{11}, X_{12}, \dots, X_{1N_1} \sim N(0, \sigma_1^2)\\
\vdots \\
& X_{k1}, X_{k2}, \dots, X_{kN_k} \sim N(0, \sigma_k^2)
\end{align*}

You estimate the variance of each distribution using the sample variance with known mean,

$$ \hat{\sigma}_i^2  = \frac{1}{N_i} \sum_{j=1}^{N_i}(X_{ij} - 0)^2.$$

Since the original data is Normally distributed, and assuming the samples are drawn independently,

$$ \dfrac{N_i \hat{\sigma}^2_i}{\sigma^2_i} \sim \chi^2_{N_i}.$$

Now if you want to compare different variances, one way is to make confidence regions around each estimate. Using the test statistic distribution, you can creat exact confidence regions. The $100(1- \alpha)\%$ confidence region for $\sigma_i$ is then,

$$\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{N_i} \hat{\sigma}_i}{\sqrt{\chi^2_{\alpha/2, N_i}}}, \dfrac{\sqrt{N_i} \hat{\sigma}_i}{\sqrt{\chi^2_{1 - \alpha/2, N_i}}}  \right). $$